# How to check if an int contains specific numbers?

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a college Java project, and I'm stuck. Here's the assignment details for context:

> Write a function that accepts integer num and displays all lower
> numbers composed only with digits 1 and/or 3. (This program can accept
> any integer value as an input and provide a proper output)
>
> Test your function in a Java application program.
>
> Sample run 1:
>
> Enter an integer:  10
>
> All the numbers lower than 10 and composed only with digits 1 and/or
> 3: 3, 1
>
> Sample run 2:
>
> Enter an integer:  20
>
> All the numbers lower than 20 and composed only with digits 1 and/or
> 3: 13, 11, 3, 1
>
> Note 1: This program should only accept positive integer values.
> Note 2: All the outputs should be in the same line, separated with a
> comma. You should not consider a comma after the last output.

So far, this is what I have made:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IntManipulator
{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        //initialize new system.in scanner object named input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        //prompt user to input an integer and use scanner object to store the integer in myInt
        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        int myInt = input.nextInt();
        
        //function call
        intMethod(myInt);
                
        //close input scanner object
        input.close();
    }
    
    static void intMethod(int myInt)
    {
        System.out.print("All the numbers lower than " + myInt + " and composed only with digits 1 and/or 3: ");
        
        for(int i=myInt; i>0; i--)
        {
            if()
            {
                System.out.print(i+", ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where I'm stuck right now, is as to what to put in my `if()` statement in my `intMethod` function's `for` loop, so that I can only print the values of `i` that contain 1 and/or 3.

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, myInt).filter(i -> String.valueOf(i).matches("[13]+")).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: re: *Where i'm stuck right now is as to what to put in my if()*   That, surely, is the entire point of the exercise. The rest is just boilerplate.

Comment: Instead of checking whether the numbers contain those digits, see if you can come up with a way to use some digits to create the valid numbers directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an iterative approach here, starting with 1 up until, but not including, the input number.  Then, loop over each number and ensure that every digit be 1 or 3, using the modulus:

```java
public static void intMethod(int myInt) {
    for (int i=1; i < myInt; ++i) {
        int num = i;
        while (num > 0) {
            if (num % 10 != 1 && num % 10 != 3)
                break;
            num /= 10;
        }
        if (num == 0) {
            System.out.println("MATCH: " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

For an input of `intMethod(50)`, the following output was generated:

```
MATCH: 1
MATCH: 3
MATCH: 11
MATCH: 13
MATCH: 31
MATCH: 33
```